# Comparing if a time is in the past when ignoring the date component in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date, time

In a rails app I have a time object stored as follows:

```
#  start_time :time
```

When creating an variable for this field I use '19:00'. I do not care about the date component of the object, it must only be time.

When I then make a call in Ruby to test if a time is in the past (The current time is 10:00 AM) like :

```
start_time.past?
```

it returns `true`, because the object contains the following contents:

```
=> 2000-01-01 19:00:00 UTC
```

Postgres has put a date component onto my time - resulting in past? returning true, despite it being 10:00 when I make this call, because 19:00 pm the 1st of january 2000 is definitely in the past!

How can I test if a time is in the past, ignoring the Date component of a Time object? I only want to test if 19:00 has happened yet today.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`now = Time.now
start_time.hour + start_time.min + start_time.sec < now.hour + now.min + now.sec`

Edit:

`start_time.hour*10000 + start_time.min*1000 + start_time.sec*100 < now.hour*10000 + now.min*1000 + now.sec*100`

So you give the hours more "weight" than the minutes etc'.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy If that answers your question, please mark answer as correct. ty

Comment: but minutes and seconds are still in the past too?

Comment: @engineersmnky You can easily add the minutes and seconds as well:
now = Time.now;

 start_time.hour + start_time.min + start_time.sec < now.hour + now.min + now.sec

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is fairly opinionated that a time is meaningless without an associated date. Although Postgres has a time-only type, Ruby doesn't have a built-in time-only object, so ActiveRecord automatically adds a dummy date when it loads these values. You have two options: 1. strip the date off of both time objects and compare them, 2. set the same dummy date on both time objects and compare them.

#### Option 1:

Find the "second of day" of both dates and compare them.

```
def rel_past?(now=Time.now.utc)
  ((self.hour * 60) + self.min) * 60 + self.sec < ((now.hour * 60) + now.min) * 60 + now.sec
end
```

#### Option 2:

Combine the current time with dummy date of the object being compared.

```
def rel_past?(now=Time.now.utc)
  self < Time.utc(
    self.year,
    self.month,
    self.day,
    now.hour,
    now.min,
    now.sec
  )
end
```